# Sequential numbering of codes

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have a sheet where as I enter details of a product, an internal 4 character code is generated...typically 4 letters (e.g. ABCD or BADC). This is just based on simple VLOOKUP and CONCAT functions. What I actually want as an output, is the 4 letter code followed by a 3 digit number (e.g. ABCD001 or BADC007). I want this number to be sequential based on the letters, so if ABCD001 exists, then it outputs ABCD002 or if BADC007 exists, then it outputs BADC008 and so on.

I'm having trouble making anything work and wondered if there was something easy I was missing.

Comment: What have you tried? If you can store the letters in one column, the number in another, and the concatenated version in a third, it would be a relatively simple solution using MAXIFS and careful selection of the range.

Comment: TEXTJOIN fuction

Answer (score 0):

Ron pointed out what should have been the more obvious answer [in a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1785358/sequential-numbering-of-codes/1785363?noredirect=1#comment2790530_1785363). With column A setup as it is in the screenshot below, you can use this formula in `B2`:

```
=A2&TEXT(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2),"000")
```

If you want the ID number as its own field, you can use what I originally had below. If you're worried about someone manually assigning an out-of-order ID number or if you're importing old data where the count of ID text may or may not equal the max ID number, you may still want to use `MAXIFS()` instead:

```
=A2&TEXT(MAXIFS(B$1:B1,A$1:A1,A2)+1,"000")
```

---

This can be done if the information can be split into multiple columns. It looks like you want the 4 letters in a cell by itself, anyway, so this will work. Your data will end up looking like this: (you can hide column B if you want to)

[image: Screenshot]

The formula in `B1` is `=MAXIFS(B$1:B1,A$1:A1,A2)+1`. Note the use of absolute (`B$1`) vs. relative (`B1`) range references. The `$1` will not change as you copy the formula down (or fill a table with it) but the `1` will update so it always points at the row right above the current row (because we start at row 2).

The formula in `C1` is simpler at just `=CONCAT(A2,TEXT(B2,"000"))`.

Comment: Using`=countifs(B$1:B2,A$1:A2,A2)` without the added `+1` also works, notice the slight modification of the anchor points.

Comment: @gns100 `=COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A2)` should give the same result. @Grip be aware that any of these methods will get messed up if you ever sort the original data. If you want to store it as a fixed value that doesn't change even when the data is sorted, you'll have to have that value stored as a fixed value instead of as a formula. This can be manual or automated via VBA but that's a different question.

Comment: You don't really need a helper column.  Merely:  `=A1&TEXT(COUNTIF(A1:$A$1,A1),"000")`